# The action 'destroy' could not be found for MessagesController 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I keep getting the error destroy action can not be found in the messagesController. But i have the destroy action setup i don't get why i am getting this message error. Can some one tell me why i can getting this error?

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_message, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def index
    @messages = Message.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def show 
  end

  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)
    if @message.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
      if @message.update(message_params)
        redirect_to message_path
      else
        render 'edit'
      end
    end

    def destroy
      @message.destroy
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

private

  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:title, :description)
  end

  def find_message
    @message = Message.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment: If possible, can you include the stack trace, your routes, and the line that triggered the error?

Answer (score 3):

You missed an `end` closure for your `create` action. The right way should be this:

```
def create
@message = Message.new(message_params)
if @message.save
    redirect_to root_path
else
    render 'new'
end

end

def edit

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `create` action is missing an `end` statement:

```
def create
@message = Message.new(message_params)
if @message.save
    redirect_to root_path
else
    render 'new'
end

# This is defined before create is closed
def edit

end
```